# OpenCV: error C3861: 'finite':identifier not found

Tags: c++, opencv, error-handling, background, identifier

I am using opensource code prepared by Julien Pilet et al. under the title "Making Background Subtraction Robust to Sudden Illumination Changes". I didn't change anything, but just run it, then it gives me the following error:

```
error C3861: 'finite':identifier not found
```

I checked and this error occurred in the "imstat.h" file in the following lines:

```
if (!finite(det) || det<1e-5) {
        sigma_computed=false;
        n=0;
        one_over_sq_det= 1;
        memset(sigma,0,sizeof(sigma));
        sigma[0][0]=1;
        sigma[1][1]=1;
        sigma[2][2]=1;
        two_ln_sq_det = 2;
    } else {
        one_over_sq_det = 1/sqrtf(det);
        assert(finite(one_over_sq_det));
        two_ln_sq_det = 2*log(sqrtf(det));
        sigma_computed=true;
        n = new_n;
    }
```

The "imstat.h" file was included by the code in "emvisi2.h" file. Could someone help me understand this error? Seems like there is something wrong in some kind of class definition, but I couldn't find it. Thank you.

Comment: Alongside with the compiler, we don't know what `finite()` is, so we can't answer it right now and demand additional information about that function.

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb8es7a8.aspx

Comment: I assume you should replace it with [`std::isfinite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`finite()` is an obsolete BSD library function which you might find in some, but not all, versions of `<cmath>`.

If you have a C++11 version of `<cmath>` or a C99 version of `<math.h>`, then an equivalent `isfinite()` should be available. This might not be available in older versions of the standard library.

Microsoft also seem to declare an equivalent non-standard [`_finite()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb8es7a8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function in `<float.h>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using MS visual studio 2010, and I changed it into "isfinite()" after including <cmath> and <math.h>, but it still gives the same error, saying "isfinite":identifier not found.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft might spell it `_finite`; maybe that will work for you.

Comment: I included <float.h> and changed it into "_finite", but this time it gives an error for that line saying: error LNK1120:14 unresolved externals

Comment: @ederman: I can't help with that I'm afraid; I don't program for Windows. Ask a separate question about that if you can't figure it out.